# WSO2 Routing based on message using XPath

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a situation where I want to route the incoming request to a proxy based on XPath if present in a message or not. 
For example: Let us consider the two request to a proxy.
**Request 1:**

```
<PCSDetailProxyResponse>
   <MarketDefinitionsRequest>
       <![CDATA[Request elements TBD]]>
   </MarketDefinitionsRequest>
</PCSDetailProxyResponse>
```

**Request 2:**

```
<PCSDetailProxyRequest>
  <ReportParameterRequest>
        <![CDATA[Request elements TBD]]>
  </ReportParameterRequest>
</PCSDetailProxyRequest>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ReportParameterRequestEP">
</endpoint>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MarketDefinitionsRequest">
</endpoint>
```

I want to route the two requests to 2 different end points based on the kind of request ( MarketDefinitionsRequest or ReportParameterRequest).

If the request contains ReportParameterRequest then I want to send to ReportParameterRequestEP
If the request contains MarketDefinitionsRequest then I want to send to MarketDefinitionsRequestEP.

What should I do to identify if a request contains  or  element because based on that only I will have to take the routing decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using filter mediators for this:

```
<filter xpath="fn:exists($body/MarketDefinitionsRequest)">
 <sequence key="MarketDefnitionsSequence"/>
</filter>
<filter xpath="fn:exists($body/ReportParameterRequest)">
 <sequence key="ReportParameterSequence"/>
</filter>
```

You can then create separate sequences for processing the different scenarios.
If you were looking for the value of the content of a node, then the switch mediator would be easier.  Because you're filtering on the name of the node, the exists function is necessary instead.

Comment: Thanks Colinr. I used the filter mediator you mentioned and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad that worked!  Mind flagging it as a good answer?  I'm just building my rep here...